# why multiply by NaN?

Tags: matlab

I am reading some MATLAB code to hopefully improve my knowledge. I do not understand the use of `NaN` below in the 3rd line.

As I understand it ones is a N-by-N matrix of ones so why would you want to multiple them by `NaN`? I also do not understand the line where `ret_usdvec` is used again: `ret_usdvec(sline(1,1):sline(1,2), :)... = tdata`.

```
int_cos         = length(usedolchk);
int_obs         = length(pricedatew);

ret_usdvec      = num2cell(NaN * ones(int_cos * int_obs, 4));

sline           = ones(1, 2);

int_count_max   = 400000;
int_count       = 0;
for t = 1:int_obs
    if (int_count == 0)
        QES_DB              = SEdatabase(data_base, '', '');
    end
    sql_statement   = ['select idchk, co_name, pdatew, ret from D_RAWRETS'];
    cursor          = exec(QES_DB, sql_statement);
    cursor          = fetch(cursor);
    tdata           = cursor.data;
    sline(1, 2)     = sline(1, 1) + length(tdata(:, 1)) - 1;
    ret_usdvec(sline(1, 1):sline(1, 2), :)...
            = tdata;
    sline(1, 1)     = sline(1, 2) + 1;
    int_count       = int_count + length(tdata(:, 1));
    if (int_count >= int_count_max) || t == int_obs
        close(QES_DB);clear QES_DB
        int_count       = 0;
    end
 end
```

Comment: Incidentally `NaN * ones(int_cos * int_obs, 4)` is the same as simply `NaN(int_cos * int_obs, 4)`. Oh, and it' not N-by-N but rather N^2-by-4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like they are just allocating the space for the data with NaN values, and then filling in the data with the true values within the loop. That way, if there is any missing data, it will have the value NaN.